# Which order matters comparing text sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I want to compare the similarity in some texts to detect duplicates, but if i use difflib, it returns different ratios depending on the order i give the data.

Some random example ....

Thanks

```
import difflib


a='josephpFRANCES'
b='ABswazdfsadSASAASASASAS'

seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,a,b)
d=seq.ratio()*100
print(d)

seq2=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,b,a)
d2=seq2.ratio()*100
print(d2)
```

d  = 16.216216216216218

d2 = 10.81081081081081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diff ratio between `a` and `b` is done on the basis of "how much of `b` is different from `a` versus the length of `a`", so swapping `a` and `b` naturally yields different results. This is akin to "5 is 25% greater than 4" versus "4 is 20% less than 5". In your example, `a` is much shorter than `b`, so despite the same amount of difference between `a` and `b`, when the divisor is different due to the subject of the comparison being different, the diff ratio is different.

Comment: Perfect, it makes sense.